# How to fix Burp Suite broken encoding?

Tags: burp-suite

Currently, I'm learning IS and training on THM, so I use build-in VirtualBox (that might be important). I met this problem with broken coding in Burp Suite. How can I fix that? May be someone has already had such problem

[image]

Comment: That's not broken encoding, but simply with gzip compressed data - as indicated by the `Content-Encoding` header. Can probably be handled by [Decompressor](https://portswigger.net/bappstore/ef36a66ebeb04412a52ffc17c2f5e15e).

Comment: The  plugin Is not necessary ,tweaking the option to decompress request an responses should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer. Actually, `Burpsuite` captures everything that goes out and comes into your browser and **this is request to mozila**, so you don't need it and you can just forward it.